# Finding all possible values of $\frac{a}{|a|} + \frac{b}{|b|} + \frac{c}{|c|} + \frac{abc}{|abc|}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Given that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are nonzero real numbers, find all possible values of the expression
$\frac{a}{|a|} + \frac{b}{|b|} + \frac{c}{|c|} + \frac{abc}{|abc|}.$Enter all possible values, separated by commas.

I'm not sure what this problem wants. Aren't there infinite possible values to the expression?

Comment: There aren't infinitely values because $\frac{x}{|x|}=\pm1$ for $x\ne 0$.

Comment: How would I do/start this problem?

Comment: The least possible value you can get is $-4$.  The greatest possible value you can get is $4$.  Other values are integers between $-4$ and $4$.  Which ones are good?  If you flip the sign of $a$, what happens?

Comment: So the solution would just be $4-(-4)+1=\boxed{9}.$ Where did you get the four? Edit: Wait, so not all solutions within this range will work.

Comment: Consider the 8 possibilities from (-1,-1,-1) to (1,1,1) ; in fact you can reduce them to 4, do yo see why ?

Comment: oh wait. So we can reduce the amount of possibilities.

Comment: No, not all integers between $-4$ and $4$ are possible values.  If you flip the sign of any variable, you change the value of the expression by $-4$, $0$, or $4$.  What does this mean?

Comment: If we change it by $-4, 0,$ or $4,$ then the only possible values in range are $0,$ since when you take away $0$ from $0,$ it is still $0.$ $-4$ is another value taken away from $0$ since it would be the lower bound of the set, and $4$ would be the upper bound. So, there will only be three possibilities; $-4, 0, 4.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make cases

Case1 a,b,c>0 hence abc>0 therefore output is 4

Case2 a,b>0 c<0 hence abc<0 therefore output is 0

Case3 a>0 b,c<0 hence abc>0 therefore output is 0

Case4 a,b,c<0 hence abc<0 therefore output is -4

Hence the outputs of the given expression are {4,0,-4} and that's the answer.

Comment: So only $3$ values work. And we have four cases to consider to get there?

Comment: 4 cases and you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generalisation. But for this problem it is much easier to find the values of the required expression directly.  This answer merely provides a way to deal with a more general situation.

Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\in\{-1,1\}$.  Let $S_k$ denote the set of all subsets of size $k$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  Fix a subset $A$ of $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  Define
$$f_A(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=\sum_{k\in A}\sum_{T\in S_k}\prod_{j\in T}a_j.$$
(In the extreme situation where $A=\emptyset$, we have $f_A=0$.  If $A=\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$, then $f_A(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=\prod_{j=1}^n(1+a_j)$.) 
 Clearly, the maximum possible value of $f_A$ is $$f_A(1,1,\ldots,1)=\sum_{k\in A}\binom{n}{k}.$$

If $a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_r=-1$ and $a_{r+1}=a_{r+2}=\ldots=a_n=1$, then let $T_-=\{1,2,\ldots,r\}\cap T$ for each $T\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  Therefore,
$$f_A(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=\sum_{k\in A}\sum_{p=0}^k\sum_{\substack{T\in S_k\\ |T_-|=p}}(-1)^p=\sum_{k\in A}\sum_{p=0}^k(-1)^p\binom{r}{p}\binom{n-r}{k-p}.$$
So all possible values of $f_A$ are $m_A(0)$, $m_A(1)$, $\ldots$, $m_A(n)$, where
$$m_A(r)=\sum_{k\in A}\sum_{p=0}^k(-1)^p\binom{r}{p}\binom{n-r}{k-p}.$$

If $n=3$ and $A=\{1,3\}$, then $m_A(0)=3+1=4$, $m_A(1)=\big(2+(-1)\big)+(-1)=0$, $m_A(2)=\big((-2)+1\big)+1=0$, and $m_A(3)=(-3)+(-1)=-4$.